# Blocproc in matlab with two output variables

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I have the following problem. I have to compute dense SIFT interest points in a very high dimensional image (182MP). When I run the code in the full image Matlab always close suddently. So I decided to run the code in image patches.

## the code

I tried to use blocproc in matlab to call the c++ function that performs the dense sift interest points detection this way:

```
fun = @(block_struct) denseSIFT(block_struct.data, options);
[dsift , infodsift] = blockproc(ndvi,[1000 1000],fun);
```

where dsift is the sift descriptors (vectors) and infodsift has the information of the interest points, such as the x and y coordinates.

## the problem

The problem is the fact that blocproc just allow one output, but i want both outputs. The following error is given by matlab when i run the code.

```
Error using blockproc
Too many output arguments.
```

Is there a way for me doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be a problem for you to "hard code" a version of `blockproc`?

Assuming for a moment that you can divide your image into NxM smaller images, you could loop around as follows:

```
bigImage = someFunction();
sz = size(bigImage);
smallSize = sz ./ [N M];
dsift = cell(N,M);
infodsift = cell(N,M);
for ii = 1:N
  for jj = 1:M
    smallImage = bigImage((ii-1)*smallSize(1) + (1:smallSize(1)), (jj-1)*smallSize(2) + (1:smallSize(2));
    [dsift{ii,jj} infodsift{ii,jj}] = denseSIFT(smallImage, options);
  end
end
```

The results will then be in the two cell arrays. No real need to pre-allocate, but it's tidier if you do. If the individual matrices are the same size, you can convert into a single large matrix with

```
dsiftFull = cell2mat(dsift);
```

Almost magic.  This won't work if your matrices are different sizes - but then, if they are, I'm not sure you would even want to put them all in a single one (unless you decide to `horzcat` them).

If you do decide you want a list of "all the colums as a giant matrix", then you can do

```
giantMatrix = [dsift{:}];
```

This will return a matrix with (in your example) 128 rows, and as many columns as there were "interest points" found. It's shorthand for

```
giantMatrix = [dsift{1,1} dsift{2,1} dsift{3,1} ... dsift{N,M}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this can work. My new problem is the fact that dsift and infodsift are matrices. I can use vertcat inside this loop to keep the results in two final matrices. So, how to initialize the two matrices that will receive the results before the loop? how to cutout the initialized value of these matrices concatenated with the desired values? do you have any idea to do this? thanks again.

Comment: What are the dimensions of these matrices? Are they by any chance the same dimensions as `smallImage`?

Comment: I only know the number of matrices lines, the number of columns will depend on the number of interest points found by the algorithm. The number of lines is 128 for dsift and 5 for infodsift. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a guess at a fix for your latest problem. Without knowing whether dimensions of results will be constant I can't be quite sure...

Comment: Just saw your comment - for some reason browser had not updated. `cell2mat` won't work if number of columns changes - but using the cell array will still work as an easy way to store the results.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But now I have the following error: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in sift (line 44). 
    smallImage = bigImage((ii-1)*smallSize(1) + (1:smallSize(1)),
    (jj-1)*smallSize(2) + (1:smallSize(2))). I will try to fix it and say if it works.

Comment: That error will occur if you chose N and/or M so they were not integer fractions of your image size... For image of 1000 x 1000, N = 100 is good, N = 101 is bad.

Comment: My image is 13488x14017 (182MPixel). I will find the multiples. Thank you again.

Comment: `factor(13488): [2 2 2 2 3 281]; factor(14017): [107 131];`. Looks like `N=48 M=107` would be the best values to use. But you probably figured that out already.